# How to control factor gathering in Simplify

Tags: simplifying-expressions

To make my results more readable, I need to make MMA gather terms differently.  In this example, Simplify gathers terms by common z[]:

```
expr = -2 z[D[h[x], {x, 2}]^2]*D[h[x], {x, 2}] + z[D[h[x], {x, 4}]]*D[h[x], x]^2 + 2 z[D[h[x], {x, 4}]]*D[h[x], {x, 2}];
Simplify[expr]
```

How can I make it instead group by common h[]?

My actual expr will involve a variety of products of powers of derivs of h wrt x. So I really want to group by "whatever is outside the z[]"

I suspect I could use patterns to make a list of the factors outside the z[]'s in each term.  But my attempt at that didn't work either.  Why?

```
tt[expr_] := expr /. HoldPattern[q1___z[r___] q2___] -> Times[q1, q2];
tt[expr]
```

If I could get the above tt[] to work, I could create a list h of the factors outside of the z[]'s.

```
Collect[expr,h]
```

Comment: Can `Collect[expr, Derivative[2][h][x]]` be helpful?

Comment: @ybeltukov Thanks.  That works for this simple case, but in my problem I will have terms with a variety of products of powers of x-derivs of h, so I need something more general.

Comment: @ybeltukov  I edited my question to clarify what I am up against and what I tried.

Comment: @Michael-E2 Is pattern matching the key to this problem?  My effort at it did not succeed.

Comment: Your pattern must be `q1___*z[r___]*q2___` to work. Would `Collect[expr, {h[x],Derivative[_][h][x]}]` do what you need?